# Correct way to insert caption with photo into table cell?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a table with VBA, a 3x2 table, got images to insert in each cell, but I cannot use cell.range.insertcaption .. to insert a caption. Not sure why that is. Is there a correct solution to this?

Trying to insert pictures from a folder into a table cell made through VBA, and adding captions iterating though an array.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to do? Maybe a picture?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I am interesting the caption through an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example to achieve it (tested)

```
Sub test()
Dim Tbl As Table
Set Tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture "C:\users\user\desktop\Flower1.jpg"
Tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.InlineShapes(1).Select
Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", Title:=" : Caption Flower 1", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
End Sub
```

Edit: For iterating through table cells may try something like

```
Sub test()
Dim Tbl As Table, Cel As Cell, FnameArr As Variant, TitleArr As Variant
Dim Path As String, PicNo As Integer, Rw As Integer, Cl As Integer
Path = "C:\users\user\desktop\"

'array length should cover all the cells in the table
'Use file name of your choice, only two file name used for test
FnameArr = Array("Flower1.jpg", "Flower2.jpg", "Flower1.jpg", "Flower2.jpg", "Flower1.jpg", "Flower2.jpg")
TitleArr = Array("Caption R1C1", "Caption R1C2", "Caption R1C3", "Caption R2C1", "Caption R2C2", "Caption R2C3")

Set Tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
PicNo = 0

    For Rw = 1 To Tbl.Rows.Count
    For Cl = 1 To Tbl.Rows(Rw).Cells.Count
        If PicNo <= UBound(TitleArr) Then
        Tbl.Cell(Rw, Cl).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture Path & FnameArr(PicNo)
        Tbl.Cell(Rw, Cl).Range.InlineShapes(1).Select
        Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", Title:=": " & TitleArr(PicNo), Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
        Else
        Tbl.Cell(Rw, Cl).Range.Text = "No file name Provided"""
        End If
    PicNo = PicNo + 1
    Next Cl
    Next Rw

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, is there a way to iterate through an array for the caption title?

Comment: Answer edited for iteration through table cells

Comment: I ran it, getting an error on Set Tbl, The requested member of the collection does not exist

Comment: I got it to work, tweaked a couple lines but yeah, this is what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: quick question, how do i exit the table, as in I want to write more text below the table but the text keeps getting inputted into the table cell. How do I exit that cell? @Ahmed AU

Comment: Try something like `Tbl.Select`  `Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd` : 
`Selection.Range.Text = "Some text"`

Comment: Yeah big ups, I was missing the selection.collapse